# Parse Frame Work Update Query does not work

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse frame work in android, I am updating user object in that but I update that old data is replaced with new data here my code is . How to resolve it any one help me solve out it.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", currentUser.getObjectId());
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
        currentUser.put("forbiddenWords", wordArray);
        currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                if (e == null) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_setting_chnaged, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `here my code is` where?

Comment: What problem you are facing with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you wanna update some value of your current user. Try this code

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("forbiddenWords", wordArray); 
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                if (e == null) {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView, R.string.string_setting_chnaged, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes i use that also but problem is i have already some data in forbiddenWords column when i again update in that old data is erased and save new data i want to both data old as well as new

Comment: If 'forbiddenWords' is an array, then do like this. `user.put("forbiddenWords", user.getList("forbiddenWords").addAll(wordsArray)));`